# Proof that $n(1-e^\frac{-\alpha}{n})$ converges to $\alpha$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I'm supposed to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n(1-e^{\frac{-\alpha}{n}})=\alpha.$$
It looks like it's supposed to be super easy but I'm stumped. Any suggestions?

Comment: Recommendation: Mean Value Theorem.

Comment: This comes directly from the standard limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}n(x^{1/n} - 1) = \log x$ for $x > 0$. For the current question we just need $x = e^{-\alpha}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using l'Hôpital's rule will help.$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(1-e^{\frac{-\alpha}{n}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{\frac{-\alpha}{n}}}{\frac 1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-e^{-\alpha/n}\cdot(\alpha/n^2)}{-1/n^2}$$

Comment: You shouldn't give full answers like this when it's pretty clearly an assigned question.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: OK. I agree with you.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I agree with you in a way but the OP is not the only one that will read these answers..

Comment: @RandomUser I understand, which is why I think a *very* good hint is better than a full answer. Someone who stumbles upon this question might try their hand at it. If they can't get it, there are really good hints which can help them find their way. A full answer robs them of that last bit of discovery. A good hint plus a little extra thought on the part of the reader should give the answer. If a hint only gets the reader started but leaves them out in the cold, then it's not a very good hint at all.

Comment: It's not a real homework; it's just an aside in the intro lecture for an REU.

Answer (score 7):

You can prove this in a couple ways. One way is if you know the derivative of $e^x$. You can rewrite your limit as

$$-\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{-\alpha h}-1}{h}$$

by setting $h = \frac{1}{n}$. Another way is to use Taylor series. (I'll let you fill in the details.)

Answer (score 1):

Taylor's theorem
$$
e^{-a/n} = 1 - a/n + O(n^-2)
$$
so
$$
n(1-e^{-a/n}) = a + O(n^{-1})
$$
Done

Answer (score 1):

Writing the original expression as
\begin{equation*}
n(1-e^{-\frac{\alpha }{n}})=(-\alpha )\cdot \frac{1-e^{\left( -\frac{\alpha 
}{n}\right) }}{\left( -\frac{\alpha }{n}\right) }
\end{equation*}
and using the standard limit
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-e^{u}}{u}=-1
\end{equation*}
it follows
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n(1-e^{-\frac{\alpha }{n}})=(-\alpha )\cdot
(-1)=\alpha .
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

All we need is
$e^x \ge 1+x$.
Then
$e^{-x} \ge 1-x$
or,
for $x < 1$,
$e^x \le \frac1{1-x}$.

Therefore,
for $n > a$,
$e^{-a/n}
\ge 1-a/n
$
and
$e^{-a/n}
\le \frac1{1+a/n}
$
so that
$n(1-e^{a/n})
\le a
$
and

$\begin{array}\\
n(1-e^{-a/n})
&\ge n(1-\frac1{1+a/n})\\
&=n\frac{1+a/n-1}{1+a/n}\\
&=n\frac{a/n}{1+a/n}\\
&=\frac{a}{1+a/n}\\
&=a+\frac{a-a(1+a/n)}{1+a/n}\\
&=a-\frac{a^2/n}{1+a/n}\\
&=a-\frac{a^2}{n+a}\\
\end{array}
$

Summarizing,
$$a-\frac{a^2}{n+a}
\le n(1-e^{-a/n})
\le a
\quad \text{ for } n > a
.$$

Since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^2}{n+a}
= 0
$,
$\lim_{n \to \infty} n(1-e^{-a/n})
= a
$.